# temporary directories on win 7

Tags: powershell, windows-7, temp

i'm looking for a way to create a temporary directory on my desktop. 
something like  temp#354 or so.

I thought it could go like this: 
    $user/desktop mkdir temp{#}

and the {#} generates a random number? 4-5 digits would be enough.

it should work from win 7 and the powershell, or even better right click do something?

Comment: You want to create a temp directory on your desktop. If you just needed a temp file (not a directory and not on the desktop) and you wanted to let Windows handle it, you could use PowerShell to do this:

    `[System.IO.Path]::GetTempFileName()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do:

```psh
$tempdir = "temp#" + ("{0:d5}" -f (Get-Random)).Substring(0,5)
New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Desktop\$tempdir"
```

If you want to be able to create such a directory in any folder, you could add a *Create Temp Directory* entry to the folder context menu:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\mktemp]
@="Create Temp Directory"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\mktemp\command]
@="\"C:\\windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe\" -Command \"& {New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path ($args[0] + '\\temp#' + (\\\"{0:d5}\\\" -f (Get-Random)).Substring(0,5))}\" %1"
```

Replace `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` with `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes` if you want to apply the modification to your user only.

Comment: @PeterEberle Doesn't matter. Even .reg files starting with `REGEDIT4` should still work on current Windows versions.

Comment: on right click on folder on mkdir it says application not found? I'll guess i didnt do the registration right! But the powershell stuff is enough! Thank!

Comment: @PeterEberle The commandline in the .reg file needed some tweaking. Should work now.

Comment: @PeterEberle You can modify the context menu for just your user by changing `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`.